# why finding an empty string in non-empty string returns 0

Tags: c++

I just noticed this strange behavior of string::find. I have a non-empty string b and another empty string a. When I call b.find(a) it should return npos but returning 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    string a , b("ABC");
    if ( string::npos == b.find(a) ) std::cout << std::endl << "TRUE" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Above code doesn't print true. Can someone please explain me what this means ? Since a is empty and b is non-empty finding a empty string in non-empty doesn't make sense and hence error. So it should return npos

Thanks

Comment: The empty string is indeed contained in any other string, so the result 0 is correct

Comment: This is one of those cases where you have to be careful and sanitize your input.

Comment: *"When I call b.find(a) it should return npos"* - where do you get that idea from?  In future, check [cppreference docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) before presuming such things - it explains it very clearly.

Comment: If you read e.g. [this `find` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) you will see all conditions that needs to be true for the sub-string to be found, and if you carefully check them you will see that the empty string indeed causes all to be true.

Comment: how come empty string can be non-empty string ?

Comment: @noname It is not non-empty string. It is _contained_ in it, as everyone is telling you.

Comment: Because before the first character of the non-empty string there is an empty string. And between the first and second characters there is an empty string. And between the second and third characters there is an empty string. Empty strings are everywhere, hiding in your non-empty strings. They live in the spaces between characters.

Comment: *"how come empty string can be non-empty string?"* - are you misunderstanding what `b.find(a)` does?  It searches for `a` in `b`, not the other way around....

Comment: I get where you are coming from, it means string functions like *search and replace* need to make an explicit check for empty strings to avoid infinite loops, which is less efficient.

Answer (score 10):

Empty string is a substring of all strings. The first position where an empty substring exists is the first index. `find` returns the first index where it finds the first occurrence of the substring.

If the definition of empty substring confuses you, consider the algorithm that checks if string is a substring. The algorithm checks each character in the potential substring and compares it to the corresponding character in the other string. If any character does not match, then it is not a substring. If the end of the searched string is reached, then it is a match. In the case of an empty string, no character can differ because there are no characters. The end is reached immediately and the conclusion is that the empty string is a substring.

Comment: *"In fact, all strings contain infinitely many empty substrings."* - that's a bit OOT - I'd count them as one per position in the string, though it's true that naive find-at-pos / pos += x.size() logic could get stuck in an infinite loop....

Comment: @TonyD whether either of our claims is correct seems very much a philosophical question. I'll remove it since it's not essential.